# How can we quantify the effect of pancreatin (biological enzyme) on the clarification of milk powder

Tags: proteins, enzymes

Alright so I'm trying to quantify the rate at which casein (protein constituent of milk powder) is converted into a product (I am unaware of) by pancreatin (a biological enzyme that speeds up the reaction). I've attempted researching what the product of the reaction is erroneously given I couldn't quite determine the answer.

All I know is that this enzyme essentially allows casein to convert into whatever thus clarifying any water it would be poured into. Casein remains in suspension (opaque) and then progressively reacts and clarifies the water. How to quantify it on the other hand, I haven't merely got a conceivable clue.

Yes, this question is broad, perhaps you could inform me of any other notions that pertain to this experiment and thereby aid me in my pursuit of an answer.

Comment: Google immediately tells us that pancreatin is not an enzyme, but a mixture of enzymes.  Data on conversion rates, if it exists, would likely be reported for individual enzymes, not a mixture.